# In Django, what is a function that an output safe YAML data?

Tags: django, python-3.x, yaml, escaping

I'm using Python 3.7, Django 2.0.  I'm trying to write a script that will output YAML data.  Normally I just use "print"

```
        print("    street:",street)
```

but this fails to be valid YAML data if the scalar contains characters (e.g. ":") that are used by the YAML parser.  Is there any existing Django function that can output a safe scalar for digestion by a YAML script?

Comment: Use PyYaml load, dump similarly to JSON? Don't re-invent the wheel. https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: In addition to what nigel said, just a tip: In many cases what you are looking for is a python package, that has nothing to do with Django. Like converting python objects to YAML and vice versa. So if you're searching, don't add "Django" in your search terms, unless what you need specifically relates to Django.

Comment: @nigel222, I tried 'print("    raw: ",dump(street, Dumper=Dumper), sep='')' but it outputs two lines instead of 1.  The first looks correct, "raw: 222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212" but the second line is just "...".  The resulting yaml file fails to load

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable about YAML. However, where there is a well-supported parser for something, it's best to use that rather than trying to spin your own.

Comment: @Dave Can you please explain what 'street' is and what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, "Street" is part of an address, but for the purposes of this question, I'm interested in any function that can output strings that are safe to put as values in a YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Django serializer

```
from django.core import serializers
from pprint import pprint
pprint(serializers.serialize('yaml', Street.objects.all(), fields=('unique_id', 'challenge', 'question')))
```

It will result in yaml formatted data

```
- model: journeys.challengequestion
   pk: 2
   fields:
     unique_id: 2ad46c28-1ad2-11e7-a135-0242ac110003
     challenge: 2aa58b38-1ad2-11e7-a135-0242ac110003
     question: abc
- model: journeys.challengequestion
   pk: 3
   fields:
     unique_id: 2ad4a22e-1ad2-11e7-a135-0242ac110003
     challenge: 2aabb2ec-1ad2-11e7-a135-0242ac110003
     question: abc
```